# Git rebase from master to feature branch issue

Tags: git, github

I have scenario below:

1. I have created a development branch from master. Renamed/Moved a file(Moved file a.jsp to b.jsp) in the development branch and pushed the changes to the remote origin/development branch.
2. But the master still has a.jsp. As master is public branch, the other user is working on a feature change and committed/merged the changes to master now. This implies there are changes in a.jsp file.
3. When i tried "git rebase master" to pull the changes from master branch to my development branch. I now see both the files a.jsp and b.jsp. BUt i would like to pull the new changes from master/a.jsp to the development branch b.jsp. instead of having both the files.

Can someone guide me how to handle this in better way?

Comment: When I test this scenario, I get a conflict during the rebase attempt (which is what I would expect).  During conflict resolution the `master` version of `a.jsp` would be in the work tree with status reporting it as "deleted by them" (remember "us" and "them" are arguably backwards during a rebase).  If `development` version of `b.jsp` is unmodified other than the rename, then `mv a.jsp b.jsp`,, `git add a.jsp b.jsp`, then continue the rebase; otherwise you need to do a file-level merge between `a` and `b`.  Did you not get such a conflict?

Comment: After the file rename i have made the changes to the file and pushed the changes to central/remote branch. Also I did not get any conflicts while rebasing. I am new to git, can you provide me the steps/commands to do a file-level merge between a and b.  Do you mean we should not do a rebase right?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear why the rebase would not have shown a merge conflict (between removal of `a.jsp` on one side and modification of `a.jsp` on the other).  Because it doesn't, if you want the rebase to produce the desired result you'll need to do an interactive rebase.

In comments you asked if you should refrain from rebasing.  There may be reasons to consider that.  If `development` is a long-lived branch shared by all repo users, then you probably won't want to make rebasing it a regular part of your workflow.  But setting that aside, there's nothing about this particular combination of changes that would prevent you from using a rebase.  I'll outline how to make a rebase work since that addresses the original question; you and your team will have to decide whether it's the right thing to do.

It may be possible to make this work after the earlier rebase attempt, but it might be easier to keep track of the state of things and avoid mistakes if you can first revert to what you had before trying the rebase.  You could do that by creating a new clone of your origin (assuming you haven't pushed the results of the first rebase).  Some things (like reflogs) are lost if you do it that way; the other option is to use the reflogs to help you revert your current clone.

```
git reflog development
```

The output should show you each commit that `development` has pointed to, naming each one something like `development@{1}`, `development@{2}`, etc.  You would identify the one from just before the rebase and do a `reset`.  For example, I assume the rebase was the most recent thing that caused the `development` ref to change, in which case the pre-rebase state would be `development@{!}`.

```
git checkout development
git reset --hard development@{1}
```

Next you restart the rebase, in interactive mode.

```
git rebase --interactive master development
```

You'll get an editor with a list of the commits on the `development` branch.  It will look something like

```
pick aaaaaaaa Some changes
pick bbbbbbbb move a.jsp to b.jsp; maybe more changes
pick cccccccc more changes
```

Locate the commit in which you moved `a.jsp` to `b.jsp` (`bbbbbbbb` in the above example) and change the word `pick` at the beginning of that line to `edit`.  Save and close the editor.  At this point the rebase processing should start.

What you do next depends on what git does.  Since you indicated that it completed the rebase without conflicts before, I assume there will again be no conflict; so processing will stop after `bbbbbbbb` has been replayed.

If `bbbbbbbb` only moved the file without changes, then you can simply

```
mv a.jsp b.jsp
git add a.jsp b.jsp
git commit --amend
```

and then continue the rebase.  Note that if `aaaaaaaa` changed `a.jsp`, that's ok; git will have already merged those changes in when it replayed `aaaaaaaa`.  Similarly, if `cccccccc` changes `b.jsp`, that doesn't matter at this point.  We're only concerned if `bbbbbbbb`, in addition to renaming the file, also changed it.  If it did, then you may need to tell git to combine the changes (possibly by doing a file-level merge).

A little extra caution is warranted here in my opinion, because the rebase isn't behaving the way I'd expect (in that it didn't see `development`s move of `a.jsp` to `b.jsp` as conflicting with `master`s changes to `a.jsp`).  So I would take a look at `b.jsp` and verify what changes git has already put into it.  Ideally it would already reflect the changes from `master` (though I don't think it will; if it did, I wouldn't expect `a.jsp` to be present).

In the event that it *does* include the changes from `master`, you're in luck.  All you have to do is remove `a.jsp`:

```
rm a.jsp
git add a.jsp
git commit --amend
```

But otherwise, I expect you'll find that `a.jsp` contains the changes from `master` plus any changes from `aaaaaaaa`, while `b.jsp` contains any changes from `aaaaaaaa` and `bbbbbbbb`.  In a `merge-file` command, `b.jsp` would be the "current file" (sometimes called "ours") and `a.jsp` would be the "other file" (sometimes called "theirs").  We need to obtain the base file.

We rename `a.jsp` so that we won't lose track of the "theirs" version when we checkout the base version.

```
mv a.jsp a.jsp.theirs
git checkout HEAD^^ -- a.jsp
```

The `checkout` command grabs the version of `a.jsp` from the rewritten version of the `aaaaaaaa` commit (the last commit before the one that moved `a` to `b`).  This should contain all of the changes that are in both "ours" and "theirs", and no other changes, so it is a good merge base.  So

```
git merge-file b.jsp a.jsp a.jsp.theirs
```

This will perform the file-level merge.  It could record a conflict (much like any regular merge in git could), which you'd have to resolve by editing `b.jsp`.  Once that's taken care of, you can remove `a.jsp` and `a.jsp.theirs`.  Then

```
git add a.jsp b.jsp
git commit --amend
```

So basically all roads lead to this `commit --amend` command, and once that's done you can restart the rebase

```
git rebase --continue
```

If subsequent commits (`cccccccc`) contain changes to `b.jsp`, *hopefully* they'll just be merged in (but it's possible conflicts would result, requiring further intervention).